# Is there a very simple front-end for MySQL tables?

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net

I'm looking for a front-end that's *very* simple, to access a to-be-built MySQL Database. I actually need it for only one table. I was thinking that the user could search in a way that would ask for values for each field of that table, and give the option of leaving it blank. Then, it would return all the entries that match up with the query.

You've probably noticed already, but I'm kind of new to database. If you could point me in the right direction, that would be fantastic.

Also, I'm willing to right a little app myself. I've done apps that use simple commands like "SELECT this FROM that", or whatever. If I do that, I'm going to do it in VB, since I only know C and VB, and it has to be on Windows (I'm volunteering at a med center that apparently only uses Windows).

What do you guys think is a better idea?

Anyway thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option you have would be to build a simple front-end to the data using MS Access. It's intended for tasks like this, and you can use mySQL as a backend database using [myODBC](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/).

Alternatively, look at [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com). It is not going to be as simple as your users need it to be, but it's very nice to use and requires no additional setup work. You could create a user with the right to only edit the relevant tables and hide everything else.

Answer (score 2):

there is this tools bundle.

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html

but you need something like form for searching where you can build queries like with an HTML editor, Wysiwyg. 
i found that the best tool for this was Microsoft Access actually. You can connect it to external databases and use a form for this.

Also a short google search came up with HeidiSql http://www.heidisql.com/ . This should solve your problem.

Comment: Yeah, while I was researching the subject, as I'm still doing now, I did come across that. However, I wanted it to be really really simple. The people I'm helping out are using excel now, and I want to set up a system which will speed things up considerably, yet keep everything simple.

Answer (score 0):

If your existing users are using Excel, have you considered using the Data Connection Wizard in Excel to import your data from MySQL?

Comment: Good idea, but it won't be a two-way street (changes in the excel sheet getting copied back into mySQL automatically). Otherwise, this would be the perfect solution.